# If $|\nabla F| > 1$ and $|F| \le 1$, is there a zero nearby?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification, alternative-proof, gradient-flows

I saw this claim, stated without much explanation, in an article I'm reading:

> Let $F:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ be a $C^1$ function which satisfies $|\nabla F|>1$ everywhere.
>
> We know that $|F(0)| \le 1$.
>
> Then there is a point $x$ which is at most distance $1$ away from $0$, such that $F(x) = 0$.

I'm trying to justify this claim for my own understanding. Here is how I proved it:

> According to (???), we can find a (unique?) "flow curve" $\gamma:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^n$ satisfying:
>   $$\dot \gamma(t) = \nabla F(\gamma(t))$$
>   $$\gamma(0) = 0$$
>   Look at $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}:t \mapsto F(\gamma(t))$. It satisfies $\dot f(t) = \nabla F(\gamma(t)) \cdot \dot \gamma(t) = ||\dot \gamma(t)||^2 > 1$, and $|f(0)| \le 1$.
>
> By a simple 1-dimensional calculus argument, there is a $t_0 \in \left[-1, 1\right]$ such that $f(t_0) = 0$.
>
> The length of the arc $\gamma$ between the origin and our zero is $$\left|\int_0^{t_0} ||\dot \gamma(t)||\,dt\right| \stackrel{\text{Cauchy-Schwarz}}{\le}\sqrt{|t_0| \cdot \left|\int_0^{t_0} ||\dot \gamma(t)||^2\,dt\right|} = \sqrt{|t_0| \cdot \left|\int_0^{t_0} \dot f(t)\,dt\right|} \le \sqrt{|t_0 f(0)|} \le 1$$
>   so the distance between $x = \gamma(t_0)$ and $0$ is at most $1$.

My questions:

1. **Is the proof correct?**
2. **What is the justification for the existence of $\gamma$?**
3. **Is there a simpler proof, particularly one that doesn't use the theory of ODEs?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to think you need $\nabla F$ to be locally Lipschitz, which would be implied by assuming $F$ is $C^{2}$. An existence proof requires finding a fixed point of the map
$$
       M(\vec{\gamma})=\vec{v}_{0}+\int_{0}^{t}\nabla F(\vec{\gamma}(t))\,dt,
$$
where $\vec{v}_{0}=0$ in this case. The simplest contractive mapping arguments will require $\vec{G}=\nabla F$ to satisfy some local Lipschitz condition $|\vec{G}(\vec{x})-\vec{G}(\vec{y})|\le K|x-y|$ for all $\vec{x}$, $\vec{y}$ near $\vec{\gamma}_{0}$. A more sophisticated fixed point method might allow you to relax the standard Lipschitz condition, but I cannot see how to show that $M$ maps some set of curves into itself from continuity of $\nabla F$ alone, and such a mapping requirement for $M$ would be a starting point for any fixed point method.

The argument given doesn't refer to the value of $F(0)$, and it must. If you choose $\gamma$ so that $F(\gamma(t))$ is increasing (as it has been chosen), and $F(0) = 1$, then that's wrong. So, you need to at least say "without loss of generality, assume $-1 \le F(0) < 0$".

The idea is a good one: at each point of the curve $\gamma$, you are headed in the direction of steepest ascent, i.e., along the gradient. How else would you choose a shortest curve (or something close) to reach a zero of $F$? I think that's okay, and I would doubt that there's a good substitute when you think about how that curve was chosen. It does make more sense, though, that $F$ should be $C^{2}$ or something similar; otherwise, getting a curve guaranteed to lead to a zero of $F$ doesn't seem intuitive.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response! A follow-up question: The $F$ I'm really interested in is actually $C^\infty$ so I am not worried in assuming a locally Lipschitz gradient. But I am wondering, does the existence of $\gamma$ have a name? Is it a Picard theorem for example?

Comment: @Yoni Rozenshein: Yes, this is essentially the Picard theorem. The Banach fixed point theorem is the nice abstraction behind the proof of Picard which makes it easier. This Wikipedia page uses the Banach fixed point theorem to prove the Picard theorem under Lipschitz condition on $\nabla F$. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_existence_theorem